# create extrapattern in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, url-mapping

URL : http://localhost/eg_integration/api/web/v1/devices/cacf090690d9dab14df06219ac36b3cd/registrations/pass.usa.gift?passesUpdatedSince=1232

host :http://localhost/eg_integration/api/web/v1
 controller : devices
 contant term : registrations, passesUpdatedSince

Url rule code:

```
'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                                    'controller' => 'v1/devices',
                                    'pluralize' => false,
                                    'extraPatterns' => [ 
   'GET registration' => 'getserialnumber', 
]
```

hot to handle this url in extrapattern

Answer (score 0):

Given that the url is constant, I would set a rule like this:

```
'GET cacf090690d9dab14df06219ac36b3cd/registrations/pass.usa.gift' => 'getserialnumber',
```

Then in your deviceController you get the query parameter:

```
public function actionGetserialnumber() {
    ...
    $value = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('passesUpdatedSince', $defaultValue)
    ...
}
```